# eslint.lintText erroring about the extension for the file (``) is non-standard?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am following the [ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/integrate/nodejs-api) to try and run this programmatically:

```
import { ESLint, Linter } from "eslint";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const ESLINT: Linter.Config = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ["prettier"],
  // },
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest" as const,
    project: [`${__dirname}/tsconfig.lib.json`],
    sourceType: "module" as const,
  },
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
    "simple-import-sort",
    "typescript-sort-keys",
    "sort-keys",
    "prettier",
  ],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/array-type": [
      2,
      {
        default: "generic",
      },
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/await-thenable": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": [2, "type"],
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-exports": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/method-signature-style": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-for-in-array": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-useless-empty-export": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"],
    "@typescript-eslint/padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {
        blankLine: "always",
        next: ["type"],
        prev: "*",
      },
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        allowTemplateLiterals: true,
        avoidEscape: true,
      },
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/space-before-blocks": ["error", "always"],
    "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": ["error", { after: true }],
    curly: 2,
    "default-case": "error",
    "default-case-last": "error",
    "import/first": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "import/no-duplicates": "error",
    "lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "no-array-constructor": "off",
    "no-throw-literal": "off",
    "object-curly-spacing": "off",
    "padding-line-between-statements": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": 2,
    "sort-keys": 0,
    "sort-keys/sort-keys-fix": 2,
    "space-before-blocks": "off",
    "typescript-sort-keys/interface": "error",
    "typescript-sort-keys/string-enum": "error",
  },
};

const text = `export namespace Back {
  export namespace Form {
    export type Post = {
      authorId: string
      content: string
      createdAt: string
      id: string
      title: string
    }
    export type User = {
      email?: string | null | undefined
      id: string
      name: string
    }
  }
  export type Base = {
    post: Form.Post
    user: Form.User
  }
  export type Name = keyof Base
}`;

const eslint = new ESLint({
  overrideConfig: ESLINT,
  useEslintrc: false,
});

const results = await eslint.lintText(text);
const formatter = await eslint.loadFormatter("stylish");
const resultText = await formatter.format(results);
console.log(resultText)
```

It is erroring, saying:

```
$ npx ts-node-esm -P tsconfig.json test/make.ts

<text>
  0:0  error  Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/<text>` using `parserOptions.project`: ./tsconfig.lib.json
The extension for the file (``) is non-standard. You should add `parserOptions.extraFileExtensions` to your config

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

I tried adding `extraFileExtensions: [""]` in the `parserOptions` section above, but then I get:

```
$ npx ts-node-esm -P tsconfig.json test/make.ts

<text>
  0:0  error  Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/<text>` using `parserOptions.project`: ./tsconfig.lib.json
Found unexpected extension `` specified with the `parserOptions.extraFileExtensions` option. Did you mean `.`?
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

How do I get this to work with all my plugins?

My `tsconfig.lib.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [""]
}
```

Comment: You don't need `include": ["."]`, it's implied by default. Remove it, change to `include": ["."]
` ("" won;t work), or make it a more specific `include": ["src", "test"]`

Comment: I don't understand how that will help. Didn't change anything, and I don't have a directory, it is all in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this, let me know if there is a better way:

```
async function makeText(text: string) {
  const tmp = tmpFile({ suffix: '.ts', tmpdir: './hold' })
  const eslint = new ESLint({
    fix: true,
    overrideConfig: {
      ...ESLINT,
    },
    useEslintrc: false,
  })

  fs.writeFileSync(tmp, text)

  const results = await eslint.lintFiles([tmp])
  await ESLint.outputFixes(results)
  // const formatter = await eslint.loadFormatter('stylish')
  // await formatter.format(results)
  const result = fs.readFileSync(tmp, 'utf-8')
  return prettier.format(result, {
    ...PRETTIER,
    parser: 'typescript',
  })
}
```

With:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["hold/*.ts"]
}
```